# Bootstrap responsive table not scrolling vertically on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I have:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="background: transparent">
        ....
    </table>
</div>
```

I am using the following bootstrap.css file: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css

When I try to scroll up and down on an iOS device (while my finger is touching the table), it doesn't scroll. It just drags the whole page up and down. I have to touch the body background or any other object, other than the table, in order to scroll. This problem doesn't come up in Android devices, but it seems to be there on iOS devices, like iPhone.

I tried adding `overflow-y: auto` to `<div class="table-responsive">`, but it still didn't work.

What do I need to add in order to enable scrolling on mobile devices (Apple devices, specifically)?

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else having this problem, all I had to do to solve it was to add the following line to the css of the table-responsive class:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

And now it works as expected.

Comment: This did work... But I had to apply this css to a parent div that was apparently causing the issue... I have NO idea what was causing this bug...   

I started looking at the parent div... because when it would attempt to scroll the page down... I noticed some divs would stay correctly in place... while other divs would get pulled down with my finger during the scroll

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16184 - don't expect this to be fixed anytime in bootstrap v3 either.

Comment: my main browser scroll doesn't work on applying of this property says invalid property value

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem then I removed `overflow: hidden;` from html and body. 
The behavior of Safari on IOS matched the behavior of Chrome on Android, ie, the page was scrolling vertically again. Check and see if a parent of .table-responsive has `overflow-hidden` and try commenting it out.

I'm still looking for a better solution that will not force me to alter the CSS of parent elements.

[EDIT]

Found it. You don't need to change the overflow value on the parent of .table-responsive, just make sure you add

```
parent {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This only makes tables scroll horizontally. Vertically scrolling with tables is not apart of Twitter Bootstrap.

Check out their documentation for more information: Responsive Tables under the CSS Tab

Source: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables