# Bootstrap's .table-responsive prevents vertical scrolling on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a `.table-responsive` div inside of a `.panel`. When scrolling in iOS Safari, if you "grab" the screen by the `.table-responsive` element, it does not let you scroll vertically, only horizontally. The browser will bounce the bottom edge up and the top edge down, as if you are at the bottom of the page.

I checked the same general html structure on Bootstrap's documentation page and the vertical scrolling on `.table-responsive` works there.

Things I tried:

1. All the proposed solutions from this related ticket:
   [Bootstrap responsive table not scrolling vertically on iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706505/bootstrap-responsive-table-not-scrolling-vertically-on-ios-devices#)
2. Removed `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` from *all* elements
3. Checked for parents with `overflow: hidden;`.

Note that the tables are wrapped with the jQuery DataTables plugin, but I also tried wrapping the table in the `.table-responsive` div with the `fnDrawCallback` callback of datatables. This helps slightly in that I am now able to scroll when touching the pagination/other datatables elements around the actual table. This leads me to believe that the problem is definitely `.table-responsive` itself.

Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the mobile view has a `position: fixed;` header applied.

What else do I need to consider that can prevent scrolling the page vertically on certain elements? I also noticed the same effect on a text input field, but that's less annoying since it has lots of areas around it where you can still scroll, unlike a table that takes up almost 100% width.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried Chrome on iOS, it has the same issue. Chrome on Android works perfectly.